# How can i add and submit the "Any" value in my drop down list which is used for searching objects  in my asp.net MVC

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, search

i have the following search form that contains; text box and two drop down lists:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Question", 
    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "re",
    LoadingElementId = "progress"
}))
{   <table >
 <tr>
        <th>
         Description:-
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Question")" />
        </th>
 </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>
         Difficulty Level:-
        </th>
        <th>
        @Html.DropDownList("q2")        
        </th>
 </tr>
  <tr>

        <th>
         Create By:-
        </th>
        <th>
         @Html.DropDownList("q3")
                 </th>
 </tr>
  </table>


     <input type="submit" value="Search Questions" />
}
```

so how i can define "Any" in my two drop down lists so i can write something as the follow in my Search action method:-

```
    public IQueryable<Question> searchquestions3(string q, int? q2 , string)
            {

   return from u in entities1.Questions
   where (u.Description.Contains(q) && (u.DifficultyID == q2 || q2 == "Any" )  && ( u.CreatedBy == q3 || q3 == "Any"))                        
select u;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do your drop down as a DropDownListFor and populate and bind it in a view model.

Then you can do something like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DifficultyID, Model.Difficulties, "Any")
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but why i should use @Html.DropDownListFor ,, i can do the same thing in my original code such as @Html.DropDownList("q2","Any")  ...

Answer (score -2):

i used something as

```
var list = elearningrepository.FindAllLevels().ToList() 
list.Insert(0, new TypeOfYourObject() {ValueProperty = "Any"});
```